# How to return Stripe coupons using Strapi GraphQL

Tags: graphql, stripe-payments, strapi

I've got a Nuxt app with a Checkout page, and on the backend I'm using Strapi GraphQL. I created several coupons in Stripe, and I want to be able to verify the coupons from the Checkout page, but I'm struggling to figure out how to do this. Here's what I have so far:

**Frontend (Nuxt)**

*Cart.vue:*

```
this.$apollo.query({
  query: validateCouponQuery,
  variables: {
    coupon: this.coupon
  }
})
```

*validateCoupon.gql:*

```
query($coupon: String!) {
  validateCoupon(coupon: $coupon) {
    id
    name
    valid
  }
}
```

**Backend (Strapi):**
*./order/config/routes.json:*

```
{
  "method": "GET",
  "path": "/orders/validateCoupon",
  "handler": "order.validateCoupon",
  "config": {
    "policies": []
  }
}
```

*./order/config/schema.graphql.js:*

```
const { sanitizeEntity } = require('strapi-utils');

module.exports = {
  query: `
    validateCoupon(coupon: String): Order
  `,
  resolver: {
    Query: {
      validateCoupon: {
        resolverOf: 'Order.validateCoupon',
        async resolver(_, { coupon }) {
          const entity = await strapi.services.order.validateCoupon({ coupon });
          return sanitizeEntity(entity, { model: strapi.models.order });
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

*./order/controllers/order.js:*

```
'use strict';
require('dotenv').config();

const stripe = require('stripe')(`${process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY}`);

module.exports = {
  validateCoupon: async ctx => {
    const { coupon } = ctx.request.body;
    console.log('request coupon: ', coupon);

    try {
      const coupons = await stripe.coupons.list({ limit: 3 }, function (err, coupons) {
        console.log('err: ', err);
        console.log('coupons: ', coupons);
      });

      return coupons;
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('error validating coupon: ', err)
    }
  }
};
```

Right now, when I try to run the query in the GraphQL Playground, I get the error `strapi.services.order.validateCoupon is not a function`.

I'm fairly new to GraphQL... is there a better way to fetch external data than running a query?

****Update****

I've added my order service, which has gotten rid of that original error. The issue now is that even though the service appears to be returning the coupon correctly, the `const entity` in the `schema.graphql.js` returns undefined for some reason. I wonder if the resolver can't be async/await?

*./order/services/order.js:*

```
'use strict';
const stripe = require('stripe')(`${process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY}`);

module.exports = {
  validateCoupon: ({ coupon }) => {
    stripe.coupons.list()
      .then(coupons => {
        return coupons.data.filter(c => {
          return (c.name === coupon && c.valid) ? c : null;
        });
        console.log('found: ', found);
      })
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up creating a Coupon model in the Strapi content builder. This enabled me to more easily return a Coupon object from my GraphQL query. It's not ideal because I'm having to make sure I create both a Stripe and Strapi coupon object to match, however I also don't anticipate on creating too many coupons in the first place.

My updated code looks like this:
*schema.graphql.js:*

```
const { sanitizeEntity } = require('strapi-utils/lib');

module.exports = {
  query: `
    validateCoupon(coupon: String): Coupon
  `,
  resolver: {
    Query: {
      validateCoupon: {
        description: 'Validate Stripe coupon',
        resolver: 'application::order.order.validateCoupon',
      }
    }
  }
}
```

*./order/controllers/order.js:*

```
'use strict';
require('dotenv').config();

const { sanitizeEntity } = require('strapi-utils');

module.exports = {
  validateCoupon: async ctx => {
    const coupon = ctx.query._coupon;
    const found = await strapi.services.order.validateCoupon({ coupon });
    return sanitizeEntity(found, { model: strapi.models.order });
  }
};
```

*./order/services/order.js:*

```
'use strict';

const stripe = require('stripe')(`${process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY}`);

module.exports = {
  async validateCoupon({ coupon }) {
    let foundCoupon = null;

    try {
      const coupons = await stripe.coupons.list();
      const found = coupons.data.filter(c => {
        return (c.name === coupon && c.valid) ? c : null;
      });
      if (found) foundCoupon = found[0];
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }

    return foundCoupon;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, your code to look up coupons on Stripe looks just fine! Looks like Strapi expects your service to be at `./order/services/order.js`—could it be as simple as that? Your example shows it at `./order/controllers/order.js`. https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/concepts/services.html#custom-services

Comment: I actually added a service function which seems to have fixed that issue, I've updated my original post with that code.